# If my Xamarin application crashes when it is not connected to a database does appcenter still get the crash data?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a XF application.  If the iOS or Android versions crash when offline does anyone know if the crash information is later on published to AppCenter and if so then how is it stored if my app is offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/xamarin)

> App Center Crashes will automatically generate a crash log every time
> your app crashes. The log is first written to the device's storage and
> when the user starts the app again, the crash report will be sent to
> App Center.

if connectivity is not available, the crashes will be uploaded when it is restored